# Importing AutoCAD regions to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, import, autocad, dxf

I have some regions in an AutoCAD dxf file that needs to be imported in QGIS as polygons.
I tried to import these regions from dxf but nothing happens also using the Dxf2SHP converter. 
What can I do?

Comment: Why not open the DXF in QGIS natively?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this question has already been answered, but what you can do is to add a Vector Layer: Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer...

[image: Layer]

Then browse for your .dxf file.

[image: browse]

Finally, once you've chosen your file, click 'Open' and a new window appears, choose your CRS

[image: CRS]

and select the features you want to "import" (you can 'ctrl+click' to choose more than one at a time).

[image: features]

That should work.

Comment: I tried the approach suggested by Berenguer, but no geometry was imported.

Comment: Does the window of the last image of my answer appear in your case?

Comment: No windows appeared...

Comment: Can you explain what kind of AutoCAD draw do you have? (maybe a link to a screenshot or something...)

Comment: I use AutoCAD 2010

Comment: I meant to see what kind of layers do you have, if they are blocked or not, if you have polylines, splines, points or polygones. Some information that can help us to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I assume QGIS can not access regions direct (add layer) and can not import regions (dxf2shp). Try to use a dxf with closed **polylines** instead of **regions**.

1. Add dxf with polylines to QGIS.
2. Save dxf to shapefile
3. Add shapefile to QGIS
4. Use vector > geometry tools -> vector to polygon to create a shapefile with polygons